# Upgrade to newest Mayavi 4.4.0 with pip does not upgrade

Tags: python, pip, mayavi

I am trying to upgrade to the most recent PyPI version of Mayavi (4.4.0). I see it with pip:

```
$ pip2 search mayavi
mayavi     - The Mayavi scientific data 3-dimensional visualizer.
  INSTALLED: 4.3.1
  LATEST:    4.4.0
```

I then try an upgrade, which results in no upgrade, but instead a message about that it is already upgraded.

```
$ sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade mayavi
Requirement already up-to-date: mayavi in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: apptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from mayavi)
Requirement already up-to-date: traits in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from mayavi)
Requirement already up-to-date: traitsui in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from mayavi)
Requirement already up-to-date: configobj in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from apptools->mayavi)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyface in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from traitsui->mayavi)
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from configobj->apptools->mayavi)
```

As a test I tried upgrading requests (from 2.4.3 to 2.6.0) and that worked ok with `$ sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade requests`. So it is not a general pip problem.

I also tried `sudo -H pip2 uninstall mayavi` followed by `sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade mayavi` as well as the `--force-reinstall`, `--pre`, `--allow-external` and `--allow-unverified` options. No upgrading happened.

I have pip version 6.1.1 (latest).

With verbose I see (among other messages):

```
Could not parse version from link: https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/archive/4.4.0.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/mayavi/)
Skipping link https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/archive/4.4.0.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/mayavi/); wrong project name (not mayavi)
```

Comment: try `pip2 install -U https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/archive/master.zip`

Comment: I note that on https://pypi.python.org/simple/mayavi/ a link is https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/archive/4.4.0.tar.gz rather than with a mayavi- prefix, like https://something/mayavi-4.4.0.tar.gz. I wonder if that confuses pip

Comment: Have you tried install from master?

Comment: Instead of master I installed 4.4.0 with: `$ sudo -H pip2 install -U https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/archive/4.4.0.tar.gz`. Thanks.

Comment: I have reported the issue: https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/168